# Android Studio error: Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'

Tags: android-studio

When I'm running a application I meet this problem.Any one has any idea?

- ***Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

  > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
  >   'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java.exe'' finished with
  >   non-zero exit value 2***

and this is my gradle

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
compile files('libs/android-support-v13.jar')
compile files('libs/bolts-android-1.1.4.jar')
compile files('libs/jmimemagic.jar')
compile files('libs/Parse-1.9.0.jar')
compile files('libs/picasso-2.1.1.jar')
compile files('libs/pinchzoom.jar')
compile files('libs/unirest-java-1.4.5.jar')
}
```